# Sublime ignore pattern in goto anywhere

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I would like to ignore all the files in my dist directory with goto anywhere.  Which I have accomplished with

```
    "folder_exclude_patterns":
[
    ".git",
    "dist"
]
```

However it also ignores it in the left-side project tree.  Is there a way to keep it in the project tree but prevent goto anywhere from searching inside it?